# Are semi-frozen meat and vegetables safe to cook?

Tags: food-safety, refrigerator

My refrigerator maintains a temperature between 0-5 degrees C. However, I quite often find that carrots, mushrooms etc. stored in the salad drawer are either coated in ice, or semi-frozen. Today I found some chicken that had been stored on the bottom shelf semi-frozen and quire hard, although sliceable with a knife.

Is it safe to cook with these items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. What would make them unsafe?  We freeze to preserve food all the time.  More importantly, this freezing will likely impact the quality, especially the vegetables.  I am guessing there is likely some freeze and thaw, which is not good for storage, as the ice crystals damage the cell structure of foods.  However, as long as you cook the chicken properly (to the appropriate internal temperature), there is not a safety issue.  Maybe adjust your refrigerator settings so that this doesn't happen...or store vegetables in an alternate location in your refrigerator.

Comment: Just my OCD food safety reflex kicking in. Logically, the food is still within the safe temperature zone as you say there shouldn't be any food safety implications. It is more just really irritating - peeling semi-frozen carrots is a slippery task. I haven't found a setting yet on my refrigerator that strikes that balance while keeping the lower shelved items below 5C. What I have noticed is that there is a lot of condensation build up, something I didn't have with my previous appliance. The door seals, thermostat and drain are all fine, so it appears to be more bad design than anything else.